# Javascript Regex exec freezes up after adding attribute/quotes to searched text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Ok So I feel pretty confident with regular expressions and for fun Im making a bootstrapped extendible template engine. All worked fine and when about to rap up this experiment, when I realized that adding html attributes to my search text (for example adding "style='color: #ff0000'" to a list tag).. made the **regex.exec() command loop hang up into an infinite loop**.

Now it **works fine for expanded html** and it works fine for the minified html if I take out that attribute, but not minified html with that attribute. If anyone, wants to fiddle with this issue I set up a codepen here...my brain hurts from not knowing why this would be happening: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPWgqO

Also here is the code example:

#### JS (w/ jquery)

```js
/* regex should match the following:
*  {{#if}}, {{#elif}}, {{#else}}, {{/if}}
* the second group makes it so it should be able to find additional arguments if provided.
* e.g. {{#if someArgs}}
*/
var regex = /{{\s*(#if|elif|else|\/if)\s*([^{\n]+)*}}/g
var data = $("#tmpl-test").html()
var matches

//<-----CONTENT---->
//this content works, it has no added attribute tag
var content = "<div id='tmpl-test' style='display:none'>{{#setPartial menu}}<ul>{{#each ~ as elName, el}}{{#if el.isDocObject}}<li><a>{{elName}}</a>{{#if el.Constructor}}<a>Constructor</a>{{/if}}</li>{{else}}<li class='group-{{elName}}'><h5>{{elName}}</h5>{{#partial menu, el}}</li>{{/if}}{{/each}}</ul>{{/setPartial}}{{#partial menu, ~}}</div>"

//here I added a style attribute to li..e.g. <li style='color:#ff0000'>...this regex explodes into an infinite loop
var content_that_will_cause_infinite_loop = "<div id='tmpl-test' style='display:none'>{{#setPartial menu}}<ul>{{#each ~ as elName, el}}{{#if el.isDocObject}}<li style='color:#ff0000'><a>{{elName}}</a>{{#if el.Constructor}}<a>Constructor</a>{{/if}}</li>{{else}}<li class='group-{{elName}}'><h5>{{elName}}</h5>{{#partial menu, el}}</li>{{/if}}{{/each}}</ul>{{/setPartial}}{{#partial menu, ~}}</div>"
//<-----END CONTENT---->

//#1: -----> works!
 console.log("minified html (no attribute):\n----------\n")
while (matches = regex.exec(content)){
  console.log(matches)
}


/*
//#2: ----> DEADLY! hangs up when added the style attribute..careful now...

 console.log("minified html w/ style attribute:\n----------\n")
while (matches = regex.exec(content_that_will_cause_infinite_loop)){
  console.log(matches)
}
*/

//#3:----> works with attribute, but html is multi-line i.e. expanded! weird huh?
 console.log("expanded html w/ style attribute:\n----------\n")
while (matches = regex.exec($("#tmpl-test").html())){
console.log(matches)
}
```

#### HTML (expanded)

```html
<div id='tmpl-test' style='display:none'>{{#setPartial menu}}
  <ul>{{#each ~ as elName, el}}{{#if el.isDocObject}}
  <li style='color:#ff0000'>
    <a>{{elName}}</a>{{#if el.Constructor}}<a>Constructor</a>{{/if}}
  </li>{{else}}<li class='group-{{elName}}'><h5>{{elName}}</h5>{{#partial menu, el}}</li>{{/if}}{{/each}}</ul>{{/setPartial}}{{#partial menu, ~}}</div>
```

Comment: You're probably hitting a backtracking limit ... for your regex try using `?` instead of `*` on `([^{\n]+)`

Comment: It had to do with the ([^{\n]+)* you were on the right track. It needed to be ([^{\n]*)  because args might not exist.. I was checking for repeating subgroups which wasn't necessary..arghh! 

I checked one more time, and realized my answer after typing this lovely thing up haha.

Comment: yep, that would do it, and at least you found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

And..literally a minute after posting this ... I solved it,dang it. The last group I was checking for 0 or infinite times as a capture group instead of checking the repeat within , and that subregex was quite bland causing quite a few matches.

## Corrected Regex

```
var regex = {{\s*(#if|elif|else|\/if)\s*([^{\n]*)\s*}}
```